# how to add a new value to an array which is the value in a map in angular

Tags: angular

i have a map having string as a key and array as value. how can add a value to an array which is having the same key?

```js
addToMap(childBundleRowCounter, entityId) {
  if (this.rowCountMap.get(entityId) == undefined) {
    this.rowCountMap.set(entityId, new Array(childBundleRowCounter));
  } else {
    this.rowCountMap.set(entityId, (this.rowCountMap.get(entityId)).push(childBundleRowCounter));
  }
}
```

Comment: what is your problem with this code?

Comment: i'm getting below error.                                                     
this.rowCountMap.get(...).push is not a function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A small mistake is in your code. `Array.push()` will return **new size of the array**. So, that number(size) will be stored as the value for the key from the second time onwards.

You need to have one extra variable to update the array elements like below

```js
const rowCountMap = new Map();

function addToMap(childBundleRowCounter, entityId) {
  if (rowCountMap.get(entityId) == undefined) {
    rowCountMap.set(entityId, new Array( childBundleRowCounter));
  } else {
    let t = rowCountMap.get(entityId); // Get the array
    t.push(childBundleRowCounter); // Now push the element
    rowCountMap.set(entityId, t); // Now set the value
  }
}

addToMap('Test One', 1);
addToMap('Test Two', 2);
addToMap('Test Three', 3);
addToMap('Test Four', 1);

for (let [key, value] of rowCountMap) {
  console.log(value)
}
```

Comment: @BhargaviAnde then can you please Accept and upvote the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You're not adding to the list. Using find, you can get the correct object, then using the correct property you can push values to that list.

```
this.rowCountMap.find(a=>a.InsertComparisonValue===entityId)
    .InsertNameOfList.push(childBundleRowCounter)
```

---

Since Map is used, following can be used:

```
 for (const key in this.rowCountMap) {
   if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.rowCountMap, key)) {
    const element = this.rowCountMap[key];
    if(key===entityId){
      element.push(childBundleRowCounter)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it is showing below error.                                                                                                                 Property 'find' does not exist on type 'Map<any, any>'.

Comment: How is your rowCountMap defined. This should work with objects of type {key:string, value:object[]}[]

Comment: rowCountMap = new Map();